# Customize the JUnit View in Eclipse (e.g. show Maven Testresults too)

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit, eclipse-plugin

I would like to see the Maven Test Results in the JUnit View automaticaly.
There ist an option to import the results by hand but this is very uncomfortable at work.
So i have take a look into the code from the plugin (https://github.com/eclipse/mylyn.builds/blob/62c06fac3f14d3070a3663e38baae403071263fc/org.eclipse.mylyn.builds.ui/src/org/eclipse/mylyn/internal/builds/ui/util/TestResultManager.java).
Is there any possibility?

Comment: If you have run the tests on command line or have run them from Eclipse?

Comment: I have to run the tests directly from Eclipse.
It seems, that there ist no regular Option to do that without any plugins.
The Jenkins-Plugin have this feature (https://github.com/eclipse/mylyn.builds/blob/62c06fac3f14d3070a3663e38baae403071263fc/org.eclipse.mylyn.builds.ui/src/org/eclipse/mylyn/internal/builds/ui/util/TestResultManager.java), so perhaps it could be transfered for Maven.